# simple HTML5 Video not playing in Safari

Tags: safari, html5-video

I have a simple html 5 video on a page that works in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari.

```
<div class='show_page_video'>
  <video controls='' height='320' id='movie' poster='http://cloud-coach-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/58e68874774da1c4d18b37dc9dee3c9c_1.jpg' preload='none' width='400'>
    <source src='http://cloud-coach-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/58e68874774da1c4d18b37dc9dee3c9c.ogv' type='video/ogg'></source>
  </video>
</div>
```

The video poster loads but the video isn't grabbed and when I click play nothing happens, also in the network tab I don't see any attempt at grabbing the video data.

Anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was flawed in my thinking Safari supports OGG so I just had to rework some things to have multiple encodings for videos and added an mp4 fallback source